# how to parse dat file in little fighter 2(LF2)

Tags: windows, game-engine

it is the [game](http://www.littlefighter.com/index_en.html) which I refer to
[image]

3rd-party developers release some convenient tool (data changers)

the data changers can decode the script of the game (LF2\data*.dat),

and enable players to modify character's behavior or game's flow

data changer donwload link:https://www.lf-empire.de/lf2-empire/data-changing/data-changer

usage: http://www.angelfire.com/wizard/bolt/changing_tuturial.htm

**here are my questions:**

the original developer of LF2 did not release any document

how can 3rd-party developer know the structure of script ?

how did they parse the script without any docs from original developer?

this is the snippet of the script

```
name: Bandit 
head: sprite\sys\bandit_f.bmp 
small: sprite\sys\bandit_s.bmp 
file(0-69): sprite\sys\bandit_0.bmp w: 79 h: 79 row: 10 col: 7 
file(70-139): sprite\sys\bandit_1.bmp w: 79 h: 79 row: 10 col: 7 
file(140-209): sprite\sys\bandit_0b.bmp w: 79 h: 79 row: 10 col: 7 
file(210-279): sprite\sys\bandit_1b.bmp w: 79 h: 79 row: 10 col: 7 
walking_frame_rate 3
```

Answer (score 1):

In looking for information for a related question, I found this page: http://lf2-global.com/article.asp?id=20#9